# Incomplete GET value

Tags: php, get

Okay, so I have my post.php page. If you are not logged in, you'll be redirect into login.php so here's my code

```
if($login == 0) {
    $url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header("Location: login.php?r=".$url);
}
```

In my login.php page (I'll just make a shortcut if the username and password is correct)

```
if($accountmatch == 1) {
    // make sessions
    if(isset($_GET['r'])) {
        $r = $_GET['r'];
        header("Location: ".$r);
    } else {
        header("Location: index.php);
    }
}
```

So my problem is this, when I login, the page directs me to the page I want but the GET value is incomplete.

For example the value of $r is

```
localhost/mywebsite/post.php?mode=addtopic&f=1
```

So the url when I get to the login.php page is

```
localhost/mywebsite/login.php?r=http://localhost/mywebsite/post.php?mode=addtopic&f=1
```

So when I log in, It redirects me to this page.

```
localhost/mywebsite/post.php?mode=addtopic
```

So obviously the "&" sign ends my url making the f to be seperate in my original url.

How can I attach them? Thank you in advance!

### **EDIT**

I know I can use this

```
$f = $_GET['f'];

header("Location: ".$r."&f=".$f);
```

But is there any other way? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function.

And please watch out for XSRF, if I send a user to `http://yoursite/login.php?r=http://mysitethattotallylookslikeyours/pleaseLoginAgainAnErrorHasOccurred.php` they might give up their credentials.

To do that you can just use the path and query string as value for `r`, and redirect to `"http://yoursite/" . $r`.

Comment: Dammit SO, two captha's while submitting and editing this post. I type fast, I'm not a bot.

Answer (score 0):

if your form is using post to send the data, you need to think about how to pass the GET data so your URLS are right.

Comment: I'm not using a forum but the get variable is already in the url. :)